# Storybook + React Native + Typescript webpack/loader issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, webpack, storybook

When trying to run a storybook + RN + Typescript project after follwiing both

And

I get:

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently 
no loaders are configured to process this file. See 
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

| import {dontSetMe} from './utils/shims';
| import DraggableCore from './DraggableCore';

> import type {ControlPosition, PositionOffsetControlPosition, DraggableBounds, DraggableCoreProps} from './DraggableCore';
>   | import log from './utils/log';
>   | import type {DraggableEventHandler} from './utils/types';
>       at handleParseError (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:461:19)
>       at doBuild.err (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:495:5)
>       at runLoaders (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:354:12)
>       at /Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
>       at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
>       at Array. (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
>       at Storage.finished (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:43:16)
>       at provider (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:79:9)
>       at /Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:90:16
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
>   ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:12)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>   | import log from './utils/log';
>   | 
>   import type {EventHandler, MouseTouchEvent} from './utils/types';
>   | import type {Element as ReactElement} from 'react';
>   | 
>       at handleParseError (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:461:19)
>       at doBuild.err (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:495:5)
>       at runLoaders (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:354:12)
>       at /Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
>       at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
>       at Array. (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
>       at Storage.finished (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:43:16)
>       at provider (/Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:79:9)
>       at /Users/amirhagafny/Desktop/pingpong-wallet/pingpong-react/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:90:16
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
>   error Command failed with exit code 1.

My webpack.config.js in Storybook is:

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
            },
            // Optional
            {
                loader: require.resolve('react-docgen-typescript-loader'),
            },
        ],
    });
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
    return config;
};
```

As in suggestions.

Any ideas why this can happen?